# looping over .each function , not happening

Tags: jquery, loops, datatable

Please let me know, where I'm going wrong.
I have a button and on its click , it calls 'GetSelectedRecords()' , where im trying to fetch the  multiple selected row values.

my script code below

```
function GetSelectedRecords() {    
 var table = $('#gridview').DataTable();            
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');          
            var AllData = [];            
            $('.selected').each(function () {            
                //alert("Into loop");            
                var pos = table.row('.selected').index();            
                var row = table.row(pos).data();           
                AllData.push(row);        
            });            
            }
```

Comment: You are under vb.net Tag and your code is JQuery. So, here isn't the right place for your question :(

Comment: Change `function ()` in `function (i, v)` then change `table.row('.selected').index();` in `table.row(i).index();`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying , but when i try putting like above and select two different rows, it returns me the first row value of the grid twice, instead of selected rows values. Please suggest

Comment: In order to get specific data You have to move into cells. In your code that isn't present

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help.
i have implemented the below line to make it work.

```
$('.selected').each(function (index, value) {    
                var row = table.row(value).data();    
                AllData.push(row);    
            });
```

Now it works , thanks again for your swift replies.